# One-dimensional Convolution Example

Tags: fft, convolution

I'm trying to understand 1-dimensional convolution. Can someone explain--potentially step by step--how convolve(A,B) works for vectors A=[a,b,c] and B=[d,e,f]. Thanks!

Comment: do you mean the butterfly function?

Comment: http://www.dspguide.com/ch6.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the linear convolution result [v,w,x,y,z],
first reverse [d,e,f] to [f,e,d] , then input the first element of [a,b,c] :

```
v = f * 0 + e * 0 + d * a
```

for the next output, shift 0,0,a,b,c to the left by 1 and use the same f,e,d

```
w = f * 0 + e * a + d * b
```

for the next output, shift 0,a,b,c to the left by 1 and use the same f,e,d

```
x = f * a + e * b + d * c
```

for the next output, shift a,b,c to the left by 1 and use the same f,e,d

```
y = f * b + e * c + d * 0
```

for the next output, shift a,b,c to the left by 1 and use the same f,e,d

```
z = f * c + e * 0 + d * 0
```

For circular convolution replace the zeros with inputs that are wrapped around elements inside [a,b,c].

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what exacly you wan to do with this convolution, but [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs1114/2013sp/sections/S06_convolution.pdf) you can find amazing pdf about this. In first chapter there's example for 1-dimensional data. Later there are some examples and explanations form image processing.

Hope it will help you!